# How to move a panel or frame by dragging it or any component inside it?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe6

In a white full screen form I will have seven frames from the same source. I want to move them with the mouse and save that position when exit, for loading later in that same position. I can move a panel if I hold mouse down on it and move it, from a code I got in [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa102505a.htm)

But if I click in a WinControl inside that panel, of course I do not get the OnMouseDown from the panel.

How can I move the panel (or the frame) moving any control inside it without coding on every component it has?

Comment: You don't. You would have to detect the mouse activity on every individual child control and then manipulate the parent Panel/Frame as needed.

Comment: The easiest way is to add a transparent overlay and use that to handle your dragging. You then figure out which control needs to be moved and move that one.

Comment: You can disable the child controls.

Comment: The draggable tag typically is used for jQuery Draggable, not generic "drag a control around in some visual control library", which is why the related list is all related to Java and jQuery (at least as I'm posting this comment). If you're not sure a tag applies, don't use it, post your question, visit some questions tagged with the tag you weren't sure about, and if it actually does apply you can edit your question and add it. Please don't just grab anything that appears vaguely related to what you're posting. Thanks.

Comment: @Graymatter that's a place to start. What should I use as a transparent overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example that explains what I am referring to by an overlay:

```
TTransparentPanel = class(TPanel)
protected
  procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  procedure CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams); override;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(params);
  params.ExStyle := params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  SetBkMode (msg.DC, TRANSPARENT);
  msg.result := 1;
end;
```

In the form you have something like this:

```
procedure TFormTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTransparentPanel := TTransparentPanel.Create(Self);
  FTransparentPanel.Parent := self;
  FTransparentPanel.Align := alClient;
  FTransparentPanel.Visible := True;
  FTransparentPanel.OnMouseDown := FormMouseDown;
  FTransparentPanel.OnMouseUp := FormMouseUp;
  FTransparentPanel.OnMouseMove := FormMouseMove;
end;

procedure TFormTest.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Check if there is a control under X, Y
  FMoveControl := nil;
  for I := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Controls[I] <> FTransparentPanel then
    begin
      if (Controls[I].Left <= X) and (Controls[I].Top <= Y) and
         ((Controls[I].Left + Controls[I].Width) >= X) and ((Controls[I].Top + Controls[I].Height) >= Y) then
      begin
        FMoveControl := Controls[I];
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if Assigned(FMoveControl) then
  begin
    FStartLeft := FMoveControl.Left;
    FStartTop := FMoveControl.Top;
    FStartX := X;
    FStartY := Y;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormTest.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y:
    Integer);
begin
  // Move it
  if Assigned(FMoveControl) then
  begin
    FMoveControl.Left := FStartLeft + (X - FStartX);
    FMoveControl.Top := FStartTop + (Y - FStartY);
  end;
end;

procedure TFormTest.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FMoveControl := nil;
end;
```

This flashes a little bit when you move the control but should give you an idea on how to proceed.